# How to Install PECL V8js extention on WAMP?

Tags: javascript, php, v8, php-extension, pecl

Hi I am trying to install the extention V8js. But it is not installing. I have latest WAMP :

Apache : 2.4.4 MySQL : 5.6.12 PHP : 5.4.16

I downloaded `php_v8js-0.1.3-5.3-nts-vc9-x86.zip` from

```
http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/snaps/v8js/0.1.3/
```

Then I copied and pasted it to

```
D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\ext
```

Then I ticked the extension php_v8js from wamp system tray item. When I tried the sample code of V8js I get this error message

```
Fatal error: Class 'V8Js' not found in D:\wamp\www\un.php on line 16
```

When I check wamp the extension php_v8js it was not ticked.
Has anyone made this extension work in WAMP?

Comment: this might help you a bit: http://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=198355&sid=294d4471e0759e5df23716e3f4640f28

Comment: Thanks but the link says to compile. I dont want to compile as I got the compiled version

Comment: I see. The file you downloaded is named `php_v8js-0.1.3-5.3-nts-vc9-x86.zip` maybe the 5.3 is suggesting that it was compiled and linked with php 5.3 did you try to download : [http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/snaps/v8js/0.1.3/logs/php_v8js-0.1.3-5.4-nts-vc9-x86-logs.zip](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/snaps/v8js/0.1.3/logs/php_v8js-0.1.3-5.4-nts-vc9-x86-logs.zip)

Comment: Nope not working... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install such extension the better way is to install each part (apache, php and mysql ) as standalone because you take the extension with vc9 compiler and maybe wamp version is vc11.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add I think Wamp is thread safe so probably should be using the ts version and not the nts one.